# How do I compile sndpeek on the latest ubuntu?

Tags: sound, compiling

What do I `sudo apt-get` as prerequisite to be able to `make install` [sndpeek](http://soundlab.cs.princeton.edu/software/sndpeek/).  Also, there are three options, `make linux-alsa`, `make linux-oss`, and `make linux-jack`.  Which is appropriate to current out-of-the-box ubuntu?

Comment: Were you able to get `sndpeek` compiled by following my instructions?

Comment: I haven't been able to get to this.  When I have time to try, I'll confirm and upvote, don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

Compiling [sndpeek](http://soundlab.cs.princeton.edu/software/sndpeek/) (and one of its dependencies) is possible on Ubuntu 12.04, but slightly tricky, so bear with me for this longish tutorial. The [mailing lists](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/mailman/listinfo/sndtools) on the site are useful when you run into problems.

Firstly, there are several dependencies that need to be installed. One is mentioned on the Princeton site and is [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/); this needs to be compiled from source itself. Download the source from [the site](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz) and verify the downloaded file with the gpg [signature](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz.asc)(see elsewhere on this site for how to do that).

Now it is a simple case of moving to the downloaded folder and running:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install or sudo checkinstall
```

**However**, I have found that other dependencies are necessary for a successful compile; some of which are mentioned [in this article](http://ileriseviye.org/blog/linux/how-to-compile-sndpeek-on-ubuntu-gnulinux/). I have added the others that are necessary to this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxi-dev libglui-dev freeglut3-dev libglui2c2 libasound2-dev
```

Now download [sndpeek](http://soundlab.cs.princeton.edu/software/sndpeek/) from the site, unpack it and cd to the folder, then cd to the `src` folder, which contains a `marsyas` and a `sndpeek` folder. As per the [useful article here](http://ileriseviye.org/blog/linux/how-to-compile-sndpeek-on-ubuntu-gnulinux/) , you need to add `#include <cstdlib>` to `marsyas/LPC.cpp`
and `#include <cstdio>` to `sndpeek/RTAudio.cpp`. Please place these additions near the other `#include` instructions at the tops of the files. I found that I did not have to run in terminal `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, which the readme advocated, so it should not be necessary.

If you have been following these instructions, you should already be in the `src` folder, so now move to the `sndpeek` folder within that folder and run `make`: there will be a choice, as you know, but I would choose `alsa`.

```
make linux-alsa
sudo make install or sudo checkinstall
```

Now enter `sndpeek` in the terminal to launch it, speak into your microphone to give it some input and you will get a waveform as in the screenshot below.

[image]

After you have launched the program, a list of options appears in the terminal, so you can experiment with it as you like: you can, for example, alter the size and nature of the waveform and other effects. There is also the same list of sndpeek options on the [official site](http://soundlab.cs.princeton.edu/software/sndpeek/), which you can print off for reference. You can, for example, play some music with `sndpeek` (although this was tested with an `ogg` file, and it will **not** play all formats):

```
sndpeek /location/of/track
```

[image]

Comment: I get an alsa error (the other make methods give errors, too).  I'm on 12.10 now.
$ make linux-alsa
    make -f makefile.alsa
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/src/sndpeek-1.3/src/sndpeek'
    gcc -D__LINUX_ALSA__ -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__ -I../marsyas/ -O3 -c RtAudio.cpp
    RtAudio.cpp:3194:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[1]: *** [RtAudio.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jbaber/src/sndpeek-1.3/src/sndpeek'
    make: [linux-alsa] Error 2 (ignored)
    $

Comment: @JohnBaber Although on 12.04 it seemed to work, perhaps I forgot to add `libasound2-dev`, as that contains asoundlib.h. I'll add it to the answer as well and test it again on some other Ubuntu versions.